# How can i read certain inputs only to my list?

Tags: python, csv

My data looks like this :

```
image       id      name    xMin    xMax    yMin    yMax
24-5.png    1               4632    4695      42    57
24-5.png    2               2910    2962      60    74
24-5.png    3               2976    3045      60    74
24-5.png    4               2902    2980      84    99
45-11.png   1463            1209    1240    3455    3469
45-11.png   1464            1246    1300    3459    3470
```

As can be seen there that's i have a `.csv` file, let's call it `data.csv` how can i read the images with `24-5.png` only to further processing?
The way i'm currently reading is

```
labels1 = []
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        labels1.append(line)
```

basically i want label1 to contain the same data format but only for a specific value for images.

Comment: use pandas.read_csv, and then filter the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
labels1 = []
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        if line["image"] == "24-5.png":     #Add an if to check for value of "image"
            labels1.append(line)
```